# Get and Display events on Vue.js Fullcalendar from MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I want to retrieve my events from my MySQL DB, and send it to my Vue component to display the events on the FullCalendar component accordingly. Although It fills my event array as a full HTML doc.

Here is my EventController

```
public function getEvents()
{
    $getEvents = Event::query()->select('projectid','event_id','start_time','end_time','notes','taskid')->get();
    $events = [];

    foreach ($getEvents as $values) {
       $event = [];
       $event['eventid'] = $values->event_id;
       $event['projectid'] = $values->projectid;
       $event['start_time'] = $values->start_time;
       $event['end_time'] = $values->end_time;
       $event['notes'] = $values->notes;
       $event['taskid'] = $values->taskid;
       $events[] = $event;
    }
    return json_encode($events);
    //return $event->project()->get()->pluck('eventid')->toArray();
}
```

My FullCalendar.vue Component

```
<template>
  <FullCalendar
      ref="fullCalendar"
      :options="calendarOptions"
      color="primary"
      :events="getEvents"
      :type="type"
      v-model="query"
  ></FullCalendar>
</template>

<script>
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar // make the <FullCalendar> tag available
  },
  props: {},
  data() {
    return {
      events: [],
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        weekends: false,
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick,

      },

    }
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    handleEventClick: function (arg) {
      alert('Event: ' + arg.events);
    },
    getEvents: function () {
      this.$http.get('/events', {data: {query: this.query}}).then((response) => {
        this.events = response.data;
        console.log(this.events);
      }, (error) => {
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getEvents();
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

My Routes

```
Route::get('/events', 'EventController@getEvents')->name('event.getEvents');
```

My blade.php

```
    <v-card>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex>
                <v-btn color="primary" dark @click="newEventDialog = true">
                    New Event
                </v-btn>
                <full-calendar></full-calendar>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-card>
```

This what filled in my events array:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang=\"en\">\r\n<head>\r\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\r\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\r\n  .........
```

Comment: It looks like laravel returns more than just the JSON from your controller. Is that what the problem is? You need to use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#json-responses) to send JSON, and JSON only.

Comment: I think the `events` field should be property of the `calendarOptions`

Comment: Thats the problem yes, It sends the whole html, scripts etc. And not the json data I received from the Controller

Comment: I figured out that I retrieve my events correctly, although it doesn't place the json data in the ```events[]``` I declared in my ```data()```. If I run a ```console.log(this.events)```, the events shows correctly

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the the `Route('/event')` . There already exist a route with that name.

Here is the code to get the events and display it on https://fullcalendar.io calendar.

Route:

```
Route::get('/event', 'EventController@getEvents');
```

EventController:

```
 public function getEvents()
    {
         $getEvents = Event::query()->select('projectid',
            'eventid',
            'start_time',
            'end_time',
            'notes',
            'taskid')
            ->get();

        $events = [];

        foreach ($getEvents as $values) {
            $event = [];
            $startTime = Carbon::parse($values->start_time)->format("Y-m-d H:s");
            $endTime = Carbon::parse($values->end_time)->format("Y-m-d H:s");
            $startTime = Carbon::parse($startTime)->timezone("Africa/Windhoek");
            $endTime = Carbon::parse($endTime)->timezone("Africa/Windhoek");

            $values->start_time = $startTime;
            $values->end_time = $endTime;

            $event['id'] = $values->eventid;
            $event['title'] = $values->notes;
            $event['start'] = $values->start_time;
            $event['end'] = $values->end_time;
            $event['allDay'] = false;
            $events[] = $event;
        }

        return response()->json($events);
    }
```

FullCalendar.vue

```
<template>
  <FullCalendar ref="fullCalendar" :options="calendarOptions" :events="event"/>
</template>
<script>
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar
  },
  props: {},
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        weekends: false,
        editable:true,
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick,
        dateClick:this.handleDateClick,
        events: []
      },
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    handleEventClick: function (arg) {
      alert('Event' + event.title)
    },
    handleDateClick: function (arg) {
    },
    getEvents: function () {
      this.$http.get('/event').then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.calendarOptions.events = response.data;
      }, (error) => {
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.events = this.getEvents();
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

home.blade.php

```
     <v-card>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex>
                <full-calendar></full-calendar>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-card>
```